# Change text style and highlighting automatically

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I want to know if there is an option in MS Word, that a line in the text is highlighted by color or the style text changed when I put a ":" or a ";"... in the end of this line.

For example: when I write a line and then I put a ":" It will be highlighted by a green and when I put a "." and the line begins with a "-" it will be Bold ...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is sufficiently 'automatic' but it might suit:

In the case of a line starting "-" and ending ".", **Home, Replace, Find what:** `^13[\-]*.^l` #, **Replace with:** `^&` with **Use wildcards** ticked and **Format, Font, Font style** set to `Bold`.  This would need to be run as **Replace All**.

See also [here](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm) for green highlighting etc.

(# Note though looking like one it is a lowercase L.)